# MySQL server goes away in XAMPP

Tags: mysql, xampp, redhat

I am trying to install xampp 1.6.7 in a Red Hat Enterprise Edition. I followed the installation instructions and after that I started the stack with the command

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

And I get te usual response

```
XAMPP: Starting Apache with SSL (and PHP5)...
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...
XAMPP for Linux started.
```

But when I check the status of the components of the stack MySQL is not running, and I get:

```
Version: XAMPP for Linux 1.5.5
Apache is running.
MySQL is not running.
ProFTPD is running.
```

This not always happens immediatly. Some times MySQL runs for a little while before crashing. I checked the logs and found nothing.

Edit:

the mysql log says

```
081002 10:41:22  mysqld started
libgcc_s.so.1 must be installed for pthread_cancel to work
081002 10:41:24  mysqld ended
```

mysql status says:

```
[root@localhost lampp]# bin/mysql status
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

and ps -ef | grep mysql yields nothing

Comment: Add a snippet of the logs to your question

Answer (score 1):

When mysqld *crashes* (I think it just shuts down), you may need to configure `log-error` in `my.cnf` to see anything of real use. I am not sure how xampp is setup, but a simple `find / -name "my.cnf"` should point you to the location of that file.

**Edit**

You want to install libgcc. It should be available as an RPM for your platform. Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

What do

```
mysql status
```

and

```
ps aux | grep mysql
```

say?

Also a snippet of the logs might help as well.